# "longer than (how long) it took me" - do the added words change grammaticality or meaning?

Tags: grammaticality

> He's been looking for Jenny longer than **it** took me to build this empire.
>
> He's been looking for Jenny longer than **how long it** took me to build this empire.

Are both these sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Edited for clarity. As a note for the future: If you're going to ask us to explain the differences between two sentences, you at least owe the community the courtesy to format the questions such that the differences stand out and can be easily located and identified. We are not here to play [Spot the Difference](http://www.neok12.com/games/photo-game/photo-game.htm).

Comment: I'm sorry.
I'll make sure it doesn't happen again.
One more time, I apologize. @J.R.

Comment: Nice question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your sentences are understandable but awkward and would be considered to be created by a non-native speaker.

Better might be

> He's been looking for Jenny ***for*** longer than it took ***for*** me to build this empire.

Which is still odd in using the contrast of times for looking and for building.