# Are the constructions of both these sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Now, I have posted related questions to what I'm about to post right now.

Things in our country were worse then than **how bad** things are in certain parts of Liberia.

Things in our country were worse then than things are in certain parts of Liberia.

If I used the former sentence, would it be deemed grammatically incorrect?
Would it be okay to use the former sentence on paper?
Do they mean the same?

Comment: The sentence with **how** is bad.  *... things were worse then than they are now in ....*

Comment: No, you're comparing things with how.  Maybe by some stretch it could be called grammatical in the same way that smearing feces on the wall could be called painting.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/do-both-these-sentences-mean-the-same-thing-are-they-grammatically-correct @TRomano

Comment: You were told that there that the sentence was unidiomatic. And Araucaria may have thought it an interesting question, but he didn't say it was a good sentence.

Comment: How you say that word is not the same as how she says it.  Awkward, but at least how is being compared to how. Your pronunciation of that word is different from how she says it.

Comment: Your **how bad** is not a valid comparand for "things".  Not good: Your essay was worse than how excellent hers was.

Comment: He's been looking for Jenny longer than it took me to build this empire.

@TRomano, is this sentence good enough?

Comment: You essay worse than how hers was. 
@TRomano
Does this work?
Take a look at the one answer to this post.

Comment: How about *I've been wasting time on this question longer than it deserves.*  Is that marginal enough for you?

Comment: *Your essay was worse than hers* would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**how** alone expresses manner

> I like *how* you say those words, "tins of tuna".

or a way of being

> You will never fully appreciate how things were during the war.

**how** + modifier expresses degree:

> It is not known at this time *how badly* the car was damaged.

**How** alone can be used as a comparand with a phrase that also expresses manner:

> *Her pronunciation* of that word is **clearer than** *how you say it*.

Simpler would be "Her pronunciation of that word is clearer than *yours*".  Things can stray into marginal territory when a simple parallel pronoun is avoided and a noun is compared with *how*.

> *Life now* is much better than *how it was* during the war.<sup>marginal</sup>
>
> *Life now* is much better than *it* was during the war.

It is possible to compare the degree of one thing to the degree of another, so that **how** + modifier can be used in a comparison with another **how** + modifier.  The words of comparison will not be a simple comparative but will create a new predicate:

> How poorly she sings *is nothing compared to* how badly you cook.
>
> How stubborn she is *is less troubling to us than* how lazy you are.
>
> How poorly she sings is *less a problem than* how poorly you sing (because she dances very well and you can't dance at all.)

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker the **how bad** part of the sentence makes the whole sentence disjointed.

I applaud your attempt, however the sentence overall compares how bad things are in both Liberia and your country, therefore it is already saying things are bad in certain parts of Liberia.  How you join the 2 parts together to make the comparison is where you seem to have the problem.

I would rephrase the sentence by saying, "Things in our country were worse then, than how <strike>bad things</strike> **they** are in certain parts of Liberia."

Things in our country were worse then than how bad things are in certain parts of Liberia.